# Bootstrap: autohiding navbar not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.5 and have a fixed navbar at top and bottom. This is the code for calling navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

I am using the autohide plugin described at http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar/, downloaded the js file and placed in scripts folder. I am calling this js file within head:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.min.js"></script>
```

I am calling the script at the bottom of the page like this:

```
<script>$('.navbar-fixed-top').autoHidingNavbar('setDisableAutohide', true);</script>
```

Autohide is not working. Can anyone help me to troubleshoot

Comment: You need to post an actual working example Snippet that demonstrates the problem you're having: **not working** doesn't mean anything. -> [mcve]

Comment: wrap it in `$(document).ready` or else replicate the problem in fiddle..

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/nwV2r/

Comment: Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tjrafferty/1vr902k7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>$('.navbar-fixed-top').autoHidingNavbar('setDisableAutohide', true);</script>`

You're specifically disabling autohide, not enabling it. Try `$('.navbar-fixed-top').autoHidingNavbar();`

Comment: That worked. I have navbar at bottom "navbar-fixed-bottom" that works as a footer. How do I apply the same for it to work in the reverse order?

Comment: The library has two parameters, `showOnUpscroll` and `showOnBottom`, setting `showOnBottom` to `false` for the top one and to `true` for the bottom one, and `showOnUpscroll` to `false` for the bottom one should only show the top one at the top and the bottom one at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I suggest you do to help yourself out while you debug now and in the future.

Get your developer tools out to help you inspect your page. I like chromes https://developer.chrome.com/devtools .

Click on console of the developer tools. Here you can check if there is a problem with your code .. maybe you entered a typo which caused the js to fail, or perhaps you didn't load one of the libraries properly.. it may give you some insight as to whats going wrong.

After you can collect some more information about your issue update your question so we may help you resolve and learn.

Comment: I always check using the developer tools to ensure that there is no error in the code. In this case, there are none.